# How to verify payment signature in razorpay using PHP?

Tags: php, razorpay

I am not able to verify payment signature.

> So this is the code that razorpay provided.

```
 $attributes  = array('razorpay_signature'  => $razorpay_signature,  'razorpay_payment_id'  => $razorpay_payment_id , 'razorpay_order_id' => $razorpay_order_id);
 $signatureVerified  = $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
```

> when I check it.

```
if($signatureVerified) {
    echo 'signature verified';
} else {
   echo "signature didn't verify";
}
```

**All I get is, signature didn't verify.**

P.s:  I've got payment signature, orderId & paymentID from razorpay.

Answer (score 3):

The function doesn't return anything, it just throws an exception when the signature doesn't match. This seems to confuse a lot of people, so there's a PR to add a return value: [Link](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php/pull/129). Will be included in the next release.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but still I'm getting signature didn't verify.

Comment: @DeveloperStack Yes, and this answer explains why. You're doing `if($signatureVerified)`, which will never work, because `verifyPaymentSignature` doesn't return a value and will always fail the `if`.

Comment: Just call the function. Don't do anything with the return value. If the function runs, your signature matches. If the functions throws an exception, your signature does not match.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need to assign a variable for verification of payment.
You need to put it in try catch block to perform the verification

like this.

```
try{
    $attributes = array(
        'razorpay_order_id' => $request->razorpay_order_id,
        'razorpay_payment_id' => $request->razorpay_payment_id,
        'razorpay_signature' => $request->razorpay_signature
    );
    $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
}
catch(SignatureVerificationError $e){
    $response = 'failure' ;       
    $error = 'Razorpay Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}

return response('success');
```

So, in case of failure, It'll go in catch block or else it'll return success

Comment: can you tell me what's response ??

Comment: In this case,There are two types of response; first is from razorpay,if your payment fails then you'll get the response as error in catch block and if it doesn't fail then you'll get no response, where you have to pass your own response as 'success' or any other keyword which you have decided in your callback function